# Elastic Load Balancing error - One or more listeners not found while it actually exist in the AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to upgrade my terraform to `1.3.9` and hashicorp/aws to `4.56.0` then when I do the `terraform apply` it shows an error something like:
`Error: reading ELB (Elastic Load Balancing) Listener Certificate (1rn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:...`.

But in my previous version which `terraform version 0.12` and `hashicorp/aws version 3.72.0`, everything work just fine, also the certificate that I use actually exist in AWS.

Code:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener" "the-app-secure" {

  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.main.arn
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = data.terraform_remote_state.global.outputs.the_app_star_certificate_arn

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.main.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "load_balancer" {
  listener_arn    = aws_alb_listener.the-app-secure.arn
  certificate_arn = local.env == "production" ? data.terraform_remote_state.global.outputs.the_app_star_certificate_arn : aws_acm_certificate.cert-the-app[0].arn
  depends_on      = [aws_alb_listener.the-app-secure]
}
```

I try to look at the Terraform official document but still didn't found any solutions for it yet. Does someone know what is the cause of this error and what should I try? Thank in advance.

Comment: Please provide any relevant code you have.

Comment: @MarkoE, yes I just added it.

Comment: There could be many different problems. For example, is the cert in the same region as the ALB? What is the `local.env` value?